# svn commit files with tag - part of of the file name of each file

Tags: svn, batch-file, tags, commit

I'm trying to do the following: Search through a directory and find not committed files (new, added or updated) and for each file that is found to commit it with tag containing part of the name of the file. (different files with different names it a format *_*_*.*). The file name part between the underscores is the one I want to use as tag and to remove it before committing from the file name.

Currently I've got the following:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


set SOURCE=C:\Users\Public\Documents\AutomatedTests\File_listings_export\
set batsourse=C:\Users\Public\Documents\
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\

set file_name=
set pkg_number=
set new_file_name=
set empty=Y

cd %SOURCE%



svn status | findstr "^?" >> %batsourse%newfiles.txt

for /f %%i in (%batsourse%newfiles.txt) do set empty=N
if %empty%==Y (
echo No new files. Nothing to commit. Exiting.
del %batsourse%\newfil*.txt 
exit /b
) 

for /f "tokens=* delims=?" %%a in (%batsourse%newfiles.txt) do echo %%a >> %batsourse%newfile1.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%batsourse%newfile1.txt) do echo %%a >> %batsourse%newfile2.txt


for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%batsourse%newfile2.txt) do (
set file_name=%%a
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims=_" %%b in  (%batsourse%newfile2.txt) do (
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
call set pkg_number=%%b   

call set new_file_name=%%file_name:!pkg_number!=%%

move /y !file_name! !new_file_name!
endlocal

cd %SOURCE%
svn add . --force
svn up
svn commit -m "Product pkg number: "%%b --targets %SOURCE%"*__*.*"
svn up

)
)


del %batsourse%\newfil*.txt
exit /b
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the commit per file doesn't work. It actually commits all files with the first one tag...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code your not specifying the file to commit, your doing a mass `svn add .` and a `svn commit` with no file name as arguments. Change your code so that you have

`svn add %filename%`

and then

`svn ci %filename% -m %tag%`

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I've updated the bat file that I'm using. But form some reason it marks my files as ones in conflict and actually does not commit anything. It renames only the first one, but doesn't commit anything and marks the rest of the files to be in conflict.

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator>C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\update_Prod_files_exports.
bat
        1 file(s) moved.
svn: E155015: 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\AutomatedTests\File_listings_export\filelog_2.2.00122_win7x64.log' is an existing item in confl
ict; please mark the conflict as resolved before adding a new item here
Updating '.':
At revision 552787.
svn: E155015: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155015: Aborting commit: 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\AutomatedTests\File_li
stings_export\filelog_2.2.00122_win7x64.log' remains in
conflict

Comment: thats the modified code:for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%batsourse%newfile2.txt) do (
set file_name=%%a
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims=_" %%b in  (%batsourse%newfile2.txt) do (
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
call set pkg_number=%%b
REM echo !pkg_number!
REM echo %%b


call set new_file_name=%%file_name:!pkg_number!=%%
move /y !file_name! !new_file_name!
endlocal

cd %SOURCE%
svn add . %new_file_name% --force
svn up
svn commit %new_file_name% -m "Product pkg number: "%%b

Comment: could this be because my 'setlocal' end just before that?

Comment: If you have conflicts then they need to be resolved, but your original question stated that your issue is you batch script is committing all the files at once and you wanted it to commit one file at a time. Conflicts needs human intervention unless all you need is a strict rule like `keep-theirs` or `use-mine` or something similar